# How to use name_get condition in odoo 12

Tags: odoo

```
class ResPartnerInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'


    is_specialist = fields.Boolean(string='Is Specialist')
    specialized_in = fields.Many2one('specialization',string='Specialization')
    hospital = fields.Char(string='Hospital')


    @api.depends('is_specialist')
    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
       
        res = []
        self.browse(self.ids).read(['name', 'hospital'])
        for rec in self:
            res.append((rec.id, '%s - %s' % (rec.name, rec.hospital)))
        return res
```

What I'm trying to do here is, using `name_get` function When selecting a specialist his hospital needs to be shown, so I wanna give condition only for a specialist,there is a boolean field named `is_specialist`.so I wanna get the condition only when boolean is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check is the partner is a specialist when building his name and if yes show also the hospital.

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    res = []
    for rec in self:
        res.append((rec.id, '%s - %s' % (rec.name, rec.hospital) if rec.is_specialist else rec.name))
    return res
```

Comment: and what if i want to save the name and hospital instead of only saving the name?

Comment: The partner name and hospital are used just as a display name. Please provide more details about where you need to save the name and hospital.